# Инкапсуляция данных в Go, как сделать правильно, идиоматично?

Tags: golang

Имеется такой код:

```
type obj1 struct {
    obj2
}

type obj2 struct {
    priv1   string
    priv2   string
    public1 string
    public2 string
}

func (o *obj2) publicFunc1() {

}
func (o *obj2) publicFunc2() {

}
func (o *obj2) publicFunc3() {

}

func (o *obj2) privateFunc() {

}

func main() {
    o := obj1{
        obj2: obj2{},
    }

    o.privateFunc() // <- Запретить возможность вызова.
    o.priv1         // <- Запретить доступ.
}
```

Как в данном случае решить классическую задачу инкапсуляции? Мне приходит в голову следующее: использовать интерфейс с сигнатурами public функций, однако все поля obj2 будут недоступны. Также можно сделать отдельный пакет, в котором можно скрыть нужное нижнем регистром, но я читал, что выделять всё в отдельный пакет имеет смысл только в случае, если будет нужда код использовать снова. Есть ли способ решить задачу в рамках одного пакета? По возможности с примером кода, спасибо.

Comment: Чем быстрее вы перестанете думать в терминах т.н. "классического ООП", тем быстрее вы усвоите идиоматику го. Единицей инкапсуляции в го является пакет, а пакет представляет собой идею. Защищаться внутри пакета от других частей пакета попросту глупо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте отдельный пакет obj в котором публичные методы и свойства пишите с большой буквы и приватные с маленькой и импортируйте его в main.go